# How to display the last field which is user selected from form builder with the field name and field type?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter-3, formbuilder

I am making the form builder and I have an input field which is called as Firstname, Lastname, Email, Iagree. Whatever user choose the field from the form builder page, all the elements will store in the database after clicking on a button.

Like I choose elements Firstname, Lastname, Email and iagree from my form builder page and saved it. In the database, it will store like below example 
[image]

Now I update the form builder and I change the form elements. It's displaying like below image.

[image]

Using below query I am getting the last record updated

```
 SELECT form_id,form_elements,form_builder_type, update_date FROM `form_builder` WHERE form_id=1 AND form_builder_type='example' ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

the output of above query

[image]

Now I have the second table with field name and field type

[image]

I have to join both the table to get the field name and type of the elements.

Now I have to display the last elements of the form builder with field name and field type. I mean it will display the last name and email with field type.

I am using CodeIgniter, **my controller**

```
$inst_id=1;
    $result['data']=$this->formbuilder_Model->check_example_form_builder_fields($inst_id);
     $this->load->view('user-form',$result);//passing elements to the view page
```

**View**

```
foreach ($data as $key) {
 $exp_fields_name=$key->fields_name;
 $exp_fields_type=$key->fields_type;
 $exp_form_elements=$key->form_elements;
  $abc=explode(',',$exp_form_elements);
    foreach ($abc as $value) {
      if ($exp_fields_name == $value) {?>
      <div class="form-group row label-capitals">
              <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"><?php echo $exp_fields_name;?></label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="<?php echo $exp_fields_type;?>" name="<?php echo $exp_fields_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $value;?>" class="form-control" />
               <?php echo form_error($exp_fields_name); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
              <?php 
       }}}?>
```

I need a output like

```
<label>Lastname</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname">

<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email">
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: you could use `end($abc)` after you explode it to get the last element... if that's what you're looking for? http://php.net/end

Comment: @Dale, No, I need an output like whatever user select the elements that will display in the view with input type.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing form_elements in fom_builder table, store their respective id and then use query something like this

SELECT form_elements_id FROM `form_builder` WHERE form_id=1 AND form_builder_type='example' ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1

Once you get all form elements Id implode it and convert it into array and use whereIn clause to get data from second table.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Nilesh, but your above query will display the last record only. I need last record as well as the form elements of the first table should compare in the second table

Comment: I mean using your query I got an output, first name, and last name.Now  I have to check the fields available or not in the second table if available then display the field name and field type