# How to compare the one table elements to another table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

Using below query I am getting the last record which is updated in the table using update_date

```
SELECT form_id,form_elements,form_builder_type, update_date FROM `form_builder` WHERE form_id=1 AND form_builder_type='example' ORDER BY update_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Output is below

[image]

Now I have the second table with field name and field type

[image]

I have to check the form_elements which are coming from the first table is available or not in the second table.
If available in the table then display the field name and field type

I need an output like

```
lastname:  text
email   :  email
```

Would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

will not tell you that saving data like you do is not correct way to do things, so:

```
SELECT t.id, t.form_builder_type, e.field_type FROM form_builder t
LEFT JOIN form_elements e 

ON e.field_name regexp concat('(',replace(e.form_elements, ',','|'),')');
```

Hope you'll use it to update your scheme ;)

Comment: thanks for reply, But where should I used where clause because I have to set the condition like I have to set id 1 and last update record

Comment: as usual, in the end of query
simply add WHERE t.id = 1 (or whatever else)

Comment: I tried, I got wrong output, You are concat the whole field which is related to id 1

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661435/how-to-display-the-last-field-which-is-user-selected-from-form-builder-with-the?noredirect=1#comment80271485_46661435