# Getting the last value in the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter, I am getting only the last value from the array which coming from the model. I need all the value which runs in foreach condition.

**My controller code is**

```
   $inst_id = $this->session->userdata['int_url_id']['int_id'];
   $result['data']=$this->formbuilder_Model->check_example_fields($inst_id);
   print_r($result['data']);// Here I am getting the last value 
   $this->load->view('user-example-form',$result);//passing elements to the view page
```

**Model**

```
public function check_example_fields($inst_id)
{
    $sql_elements="SELECT inst_id,form_builder_type, form_elements,form_last_modified FROM `form_builder` WHERE inst_id=$inst_id AND form_builder_type='example' ORDER BY form_last_modified DESC LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql_elements);// I am getting the last row
    $row = $query->row();
    $abc=explode(',',$row->form_elements);//I am getting output

    foreach ($abc as $value) {
        $sql_elements_get="SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='".$value."'";
        $fetch_query = $this->db->query($sql_elements_get);
        $row1 = $fetch_query->result();
    }
    return $row1;// It it return only last value
}
```

I know I will get last value but is there any other option to get all the values and pass to the controller?

Comment: Please update your title to make sense to what you're asking.

Comment: If it was me, I'd  forget about all this largely redundant PHP code, and instead see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this line:

```
$row1 = $fetch_query->result();
```

with this:

```
$row1[] = $fetch_query->result();
```

P.S.
I think you can avoid `foreach` loop by use mysql `IN` or `FIND_IN_SET` operators.

Comment: @brevis.What I am doing is I am getting the output in first query and checking the output is available or not in the second table

Comment: But if I misunderstood what you doing -- just never mind :)

Comment: Can you help me in below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661435/how-to-display-the-last-field-which-is-user-selected-from-form-builder-with-the/46684011#46684011

Answer (score 0):

you need to cycle the results of the second query ;)

```
public function check_example_fields($inst_id)
{
  $sql_elements="SELECT inst_id,form_builder_type, form_elements,form_last_modified FROM `form_builder` WHERE inst_id=$inst_id AND form_builder_type='example' ORDER BY form_last_modified DESC LIMIT 1";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql_elements);// I am getting the last row
  $row = $query->row();
  $abc=explode(',',$row->form_elements);//I am getting output
  $results = [];
  foreach ($abc as $value) {
    $sql_elements_get="SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='".$value."'";
    $fetch_query = $this->db->query($sql_elements_get);
    foreach ($fetch_query->result() as $r)
    {
      $results[] = $r;
    }
  }
  return $results;// It it return all values
}
```

Comment: Well it's not how I'd do it :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function check_example_fields($inst_id)
{
    $sql_elements="SELECT inst_id,form_builder_type, form_elements,form_last_modified FROM `form_builder` WHERE inst_id=$inst_id AND form_builder_type='example' ORDER BY form_last_modified DESC LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql_elements);// I am getting the last row
    $row = $query->row();
    $abc=explode(',',$row->form_elements);//I am getting output
    $datanew = array();    
    // start your copy code here
    foreach ($abc as $value)
    {
       $sql_elements_get="SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='".$value."'";
        $fetch_query = $this->db->query($sql_elements_get);
        $datanew[] = $fetch_query->result();
    }
    // end your copy code here

    $last_row = end($datanew);

    $data['alldata'] = $datanew;
    $data['lastrow'] = $last_row;
    return $data;
}
```

edited to your full code

Answer (score 0):

Use row1 as an array and assign the results in it.

```
public function check_example_fields($inst_id){
        $sql_elements="SELECT inst_id,form_builder_type, form_elements,form_last_modified FROM `form_builder` WHERE inst_id=$inst_id AND form_builder_type='example' ORDER BY form_last_modified DESC LIMIT 1";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql_elements);// I am getting the last row
        $row = $query->row();
        $row1 = array(); //define array here
        $abc=explode(',',$row->form_elements);//I am getting output
        foreach ($abc as $value) {
            $sql_elements_get="SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='".$value."'";
            $fetch_query = $this->db->query($sql_elements_get);
            $row1[] = $fetch_query->result();
        }
        print_r($row1);
        return $row1;// It it return only last value
    }
```

Comment: A JOIN seems like a more elegant solution

Comment: Yes i agree but he wants to show only values so i am work solution for it only.

Comment: i have no idea what that means, but have fun.